# Getting time difference between two times in slab

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, datetime, time

I have two times one is `10:30 A.M` and second is `1:30 P.M.`

And now I want times like below in slabs using PHP.

```
10:30 A.M
11:00 A.M
11:30 A.M
12:00 P.M
12:30 P.M
1:00 P.M
1:30 P.M
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: well i can get slabs, but when it comes to A.M to P.M, i got confuse.